# python - sum values between unique pairs in ledger using hash tables or dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm looking at a big list of transactions, and want to simply summarize the total value sent between one account to another

Input:

```
sources = ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']
targets = ['C','C','C','D','D','C','C','D','D']
values =  [ 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 ]
```

Output:

```
sources = ['A','A','B','B']
targets = ['C','D','C','D']
totals =  [ 5 , 5 , 5 , 5 ]
```

This is how I did it using indexed for loops, but I'm looking to understand how it would work with hash tables or dictionaries:

```
#Create a list of unique pairs
pairs = [[sources[0],targets[0]]]
for idx, x in enumerate(sources):
    temp_pair = [sources[idx],targets[idx]]
    new_pair = True
    for pair in pairs:
        if temp_pair == pair:
            new_pair = False
    if new_pair == True:
        pairs.append(temp_pair)
print(pairs)

#Define an empty totals list based on pairs list
totals = []
for pair in pairs:
    totals.append([pair[0],pair[1],0])
print(totals)

# Fill the totals list with values
for idx, x in enumerate(sources):
    for idy, pair in enumerate(pairs):
        if [pair[0],pair[1]] == [sources[idx],targets[idx]]:
            totals[idy][2] += values[idx]
print(totals)
```

With these results:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the rules that get you from the expected input to the expected output?

Comment: Also, your implementation working, but wanting to know another way of doing the same would be a rather broad question, and outside of the SO domain of specific, focussed questions.

Comment: True. I started typing in SO without having solved it at all, and then ended up solving it as I thought through the phrasing of the question (I didn't want to post a problem I hadn't at least tried to solve). Figured I'd share the answer, and see if there was another way that's simpler using hash tables or dictionaries (I tried to avoid being broad by nots saying "solve it however"). Seeing there is an answer that fits these parameters, I have no regrets - got exactly what I asked for :)

Comment: Now I see what you were doing. Beware "parallel arrays." That way lies madness.

Comment: You're right, I should probably make those into a 2D array. I'm using it for the columns of an ingested CSV. There's probably a better way to do that.

Comment: The parallel arrays are required for the tool I import these results to: https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = dict.fromkeys(zip(sources, targets), 0)
for s, t, v in zip(sources, targets, values): d[(s, t)] += v
d
# {('A', 'C'): 5, ('A', 'D'): 5, ('B', 'C'): 5, ('B', 'D'): 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by d.b is good, but can be improved by using `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

sources = ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']
targets = ['C','C','C','D','D','C','C','D','D']
values =  [ 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 ]

d = defaultdict(int)

for s, t, v in zip(sources, targets, values): 
    d[(s, t)] += v
```

Now `d` is:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {('A', 'C'): 5, ('A', 'D'): 5, ('B', 'C'): 5, ('B', 'D'): 5})
```

Comment: What difference does the `<class 'int'>,` do at the beginning?

Comment: You're seeing the representation of a `defaultdict`. You can convert this to a regular `dict` with `dict(d)`.

Comment: Oh interesting. So it creates default values of `0` if they are asked for. I like the dict since it doesn't require another library for this use-case, but I'll keep defaultdict in mind for the future. In converting back to parallel arrays, this code works on both of them.
`# Convert dict to 2D arrays`<br>
`totals = []`<br>
`for value in d:`<br>
`    totals.append([value[0],value[1],d[(value[0],value[1])]])`<br>
`print(totals)`<br>

Comment: Python code in comments doesn't work very well, as you can't format the code to preserve indentation.

Comment: Lol, I see. Here they are in GitHub if it helps: https://github.com/OhioAdam/sankey-transactions/blob/main/stackoverflow.py#L11-L15